# How do I concatenate newlines in Java?

Tags: java, string, newline

I've got a very strange question. Say I am implementing an object that has a `toString()` method that returns a *single* string formatted in a square, as such:

```
010203
040506
070809
```

Now, clearly the entire string, when listed character-wise (and excluding the terminating `\0`), is as such:

```
010203\n040506\n070809\n
```

How would I go about concatenating entire square blocks like these? For instance, if I wanted to have:

```
010203     101112    010203101112
040506  +  131415 =  040506131415
070809     161718    070809161718
```

How could I do this? Note that I cannot import `Java.util` or *any* other classes.

**Edit**:
The example above was merely an example; ideally I'd like the solution to be extensible to an arbitrarily large number of 'square objects', where I could just call a hypothetical `aSquareObject.squareConcat(otherSquareObject).squareConcat(anotherSquareObject).....squareConcat(finalSquareObject)` method and it'd spit out two, three, five, fifteen squares side by side.

Comment: Have you tried something already?

Comment: [What hinders you from printing just that block out?](https://ideone.com/AeKyIi)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I attempted solving this on paper, and arrived at a similar solution to that of @mayamar's:

```
 public String sqConcat(String string1, String string2)
 {
    String[] rows1 = string1.split("\n");
    String[] rows2 = string2.split("\n");

    return new String(rows1[0] + rows2[0] + "\n"
                    + rows1[1] + rows2[1] + "\n"
                    + rows1[2] + rows2[2] + "\n");
 }
```

Thanks for the help, everyone.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class T27Concat {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s1 = "010203\n040506\n070809";
    String s2 = "101112\n131415\n161718";

    String plus = "   \n + \n   ";
    String equals = "   \n = \n   ";

    System.out.println(concat(concat(concat(concat(s1, plus), s2), equals), concat(s1, s2)));
}

public static String concat(String s, String t) {
    String[] ss = s.split("\n");
    String[] tt = t.split("\n");
    String result = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < ss.length; i++) {
        result += ss[i] + tt[i] + "\n";
    }
    return result.substring(0, result.length() - 1);
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class multiDarr {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        String str1 = "010203\n040506\n070809\n";
        String str2 = "010203\n040506\n070809\n";

        String ttl = "";



        for(int i = 0;i<str1.length();i= i+7){
            ttl = ttl + str1.substring(i,i+6);
            ttl = ttl +str2.substring(i,i+6);
            ttl = ttl+'\n';

        }
        System.out.println(ttl);
        //System.out.println(ttl);




    }


}
```

you have to tune i = i+ n for your need , i put 7  because your original string have 6 chars,

result - 
010203010203
040506040506
070809070809